# How to create a volume group for mounted root volume

Tags: debian, partition

I have a Debian Jessie 8.2 system with already created root volume. There are no any volume groups. Is it possible to create a volume group for mounted root volume? It's ok if data will be erased.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to unmount it. Boot an installer from a CD, USB-stick or via netboot, and create the VG from there.